# Did Newt Scamander participate in either of the two wars against Voldemort and his Death Eaters?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

Did Newt Scamander participate in either of the two wars against Voldemort and his Death Eaters?

Do we ever see him get mentioned in the Harry Potter books or movies to have joined the Order of the Phoenix organized by Dumbledore?

We know that Newt Scamander helped in the fight against Grindelwald, a dark wizard who was Dumbledore's enemy, so would he have fought against Voldemort as well, who was also Dumbledore's enemy?

We know that Newt Scamander is still alive by the 1990s as he was living in Dorset with his wife, Tina Goldstein.

Comment: Apart from being the author of a school book used at Hogwarts, he is not mentioned in the original series. It is possible that he could die in the fight against Grindelwald.

Answer (score 7):

## Newt opposing the Dark Lord is never mentioned in the series.

Though it’s possible that Newt could have been in the opposing forces against the Dark Lord, he’s never mentioned as taking part in the fight against him in any way. However, there are likely some opponents of the Dark Lord that aren’t mentioned specifically, so it’s not certain that he didn’t.

## Newt has only been previously mentioned as a textbook author.

Newt’s name has only ever been mentioned once in the seven Harry Potter books, and that was as the author of *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, a textbook on the Hogwarts book list.

> “Set Books
>
> *All students should have a copy of each of the following:*
>
> The Standard Book of Spells (Grade 1) by *Miranda Goshawk*
>
> A History of Magic by *Bathilda Bagshot*
>
> Magical Theory by *Adalbert Waffling*
>
> A Beginner’s Guide to Transfiguration by *Emeric Switch*
>
> One Thousand Magical Herbs and Fungi by *Phyllida Spore*
>
> Magical Drafts and Potions by *Arsenius Jigger*
>
> Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them by *Newt Scamander*
>
> The Dark Forces: A Guide to Self-Protection by *Quentin Trimble*” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 5 (Diagon Alley)*</sup></sub>

He’s also the in-universe author of the companion book *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* and a few more details about him are given in the foreword as that’s supposed to be his book, but he’s not mentioned as helping fight the Dark Lord in that either.

Comment: Also, he'd be quite old by the Harry Potter events, potentially retired or living abroad.